# ReactRouter v5 refresh gets a 404

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, react-router

I can go to my root route, navigate using links within the app, but when I go directly to or refresh a non-root route (in production only) I get the following error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I have a project set up with `ReactRouter v5.0.1`. 
I am using `BrowserRouter` wrapper, I don't want to use `HashRouter` because of URLs looking nice.

When I refresh or go to a path that is not a root route (eg: `____/user/article`):

- in local, it works as expected
- in production (Heroku), it gives a `Cannot get /user/article`

I have looked up the issue and the solutions I found were to change my `webpack.js`:

- add `historyApiFallback: true` to `devServer`
- add `publicPath:'/'` to `output`

These have been unable to solve my issue.

My frontend client is inside my nodejs "app" where the built files are served up by an express server. Maybe this may affect my refresh?

Help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: you need to let your server return `index.html` file for non-api routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a client vs server side routing issue. When navigating around on front end, it's all client side routing. But when you refresh the page, it does a request to the back end with that route. So in your express server, you need a catch all route, defined after all other routes, that redirects them to the root path `/`, e.g.

`app.get('*', function(req, res) { /* redirect to / here */ });`

There's a bunch of posts about this already if you want some more in depth exploration of the issue, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: Thanks heaps for your answer, I did not realise it was an express issue. I found that exact post a few minutes ago... I am trying figure out how to use that with my non api routes.